# UID mapping between NFS resource mounted in a RHEL Linux and Windows 2012 Server

Tags: windows, nfs

I have a NAS resource mounted on linux RHEL and windows 2012, on the windows machine I can mount the resource but I can not access it.

The Linux NAS Share resource has mounted in Win 2012 how 770 permissions, The LDAP user logon that i use have the same GID number that have the NAS resource in Linux.

when i tried to enter the NAS resource in Win, say the message "Access is denied."

I confuse because should validate with group security, it is going by OTHERS. (have 0).

Any Idea...

Thanks in advance.